# How can display maps on Jupyter notebook when we put in Github

Tags: git, github, ipython

I just started to put my a few Python project to Github. My project was created with Jupyter notebook and it have a few maps but When I shared my Project on Github everything is OK but I cannot see maps and a few specific graphs (The plotly graphs).

Do we have any solution for it?

I tried many times only put ipynb. code
Shall I change ipynb to html?

I need all your advise.

Comment: I have the same issue here. It looks like folium doesn't handle the HTML well on jupiter. :(   Did you find out the solution to the problem?

Comment: Hey @overloading. My solution pretty basic might you do not like, for Plotly I embed HTML code for my Plotly graphs and then I am trying to put Github. Also when you convert HTML file again some might be some Graphs have a problem.  I am still looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ website to generate a link for your notebook.
for example:

1. copy your github notebook url
2. paste it into the textbox inside nbviewer website home page and click go, it will navigate to your notebook with maps appearance.